# onHover state doesn't appear in IE 8 while jQuery cycle() runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, png, drop-down-menu

I have a problem that the onHover state doesn't appear while the jQuery .cycle() plugin runs (tested on IE8, works fine in modern versions of Firefox and Chrome).

The site is located here: http://obh.co.il

The site is in Hebrew, but that shouldn't affect anything... When the slideshow images cycle, the red background on the **drop-down menus** doesn't appear (during its' onHover state).

Also, the image transition is a little laggy in IE, but perhaps that's just my computer not being good.

Could anyone find a possible solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay never mind, I found the solution. I had to apply the following IE-specific style to the sub-menu link anchors within the list items:

```
ul.sub-menu li a { filter: 0; }
```

I hope this can help someone out there.

Also, I'd love to hear a solution for the laggy transitions in IE8 if anyone's got any suggestions!